# Connect-ServiceFabricCluster to an on premises Service Fabric failing

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I got service fabric to install on to my virtual machines running in my local datacenter.

But I can't seem to connect to it via power shell. (I can connect via the Explorer)

My cluster setting s(when I setup the cluster) had `"name": "SrvBldCluster"` in the config.  So I assume the endpoint I need to connect to is: `SrvBldCluster.mydomain.net:19000`.

When I try that I get the following errors:

> WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
>   WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
>   False
>   WARNING: No such host is known
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "SrvBldCluster.mydomain.net:1900 ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricTransientException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster

I have tried connecting several different ways:

Using an individual server name instead of the cluster name:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "srvclusterbld01.mydomain.net:19000"
```

This caused the "No such host is known" warning to go away and the line after it to be replaced with:

> Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : Could not ping any of the provided Service Fabric gateway endpoints.

Using the gMSA account that I used to secure the network:

```
$ConnectArgs = @{  ConnectionEndpoint = 'SrvBldCluster.mydomain.net:19000'; WindowsCredential = $True; ClusterSpn = ServiceFabric/SrvBldCluster.mydomain.net'  }

Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @connectArgs
```

This gave the same error as the first try.

I feel like I don't have the right endpoint, but no documentation tells you what your endpoint will be...

**Can anyone give me an example of how to connection to a on premises Service Fabric cluster? (that does not use a certificate for security.)**

Comment: Is port 19000 open? Does blah.mydomain.net resolve to correct IP? Can you connect via ip:19000?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: some one mentioned not to use HTTP (: